# search text box in jsp

Tags: jsp, search, textbox

How to implement when i enter some letters in text box it will fetch the data from mysql database and show all related  words in JSP page as textbox list similar to google textbox . Im working on spring framework.

1.when a text is entered in the box then related text should be displayed as a list by fetching from database

2.when displayed text list selected, relevant action should be performed with that selection

If this is to be implemented using Ajax please explain me how to do. I'm new to Ajax

Comment: Please try some coding before post here the whole solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin **Autocomplete**

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

You will find a lot of examples there as well.